# How to Rotate this anticlose wise and start the countdown in reverse order

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a simple sample code which is working fine but the timer is increasing in a clockwise direction. I want to do the same in an anticlockwise direction and timer should reduce. For instance 10, 9, 8 .......0 sec

Current code is 1 2 3 ....10 sec, also the circle is filling in a clockwise direction.

```js
/*
    to modify total time, just input on variable totaltime
    */
var totaltime = 60;

function update(percent) {
  var deg;
  if (percent < (totaltime / 2)) {
    deg = 90 + (360 * percent / totaltime);
    $('.pie').css('background-image',
      'linear-gradient(' + deg + 'deg, transparent 50%, white 50%),linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%, transparent 50%)'
    );
  } else if (percent >= (totaltime / 2)) {
    deg = -90 + (360 * percent / totaltime);
    $('.pie').css('background-image',
      'linear-gradient(' + deg + 'deg, transparent 50%, #1fbba6 50%),linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%, transparent 50%)'
    );
  }
}
var count = parseInt($('#time').text());
myCounter = setInterval(function() {
  count += 1;
  $('#time').html(count);
  update(count);

  if (count == totaltime) clearInterval(myCounter);
}, 1000);
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300);
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  background: #b4f2ea;
}

.pie {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #1fbba6;
  border: 2px solid #1fbba6;
  float: left;
  margin: 2em;
}

.pie .block {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

#time {
  font-size: 3em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  left: 43%;
  color: #999999;
}

.degree {
  /*90 + ( 360 * .1 )*/
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, white 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pie degree">
  <span class="block"></span>
  <span id="time">0</span>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want to reverse the order after the count reach to 60? or you want to start directly from 60 onload?

Comment: so on load directly start 60, 59, 58 till 0 sec and also show an alert like done after 0 secs

Comment: Thank you @Mohamed-Yousef. Your answer works

Comment: Sorry for deleting my comment .. cause @Fcmam5 made a good effort in his answer .. anyway good Luck and have a nice day :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to make 3 changes

- In your HTML: Make it start from 10 for example `<span id="time">10</span>`

In your JavaScript, you need to update these 3 parts:

```
// update this
var totaltime = 10;
...
//Don't forget to decrement your counter
count -= 1;
...
// set the condition to === 0 (and not totalTime)
if (count === 0) clearInterval(myCounter);
```

---

The Full example:

```js
/*
    to modify total time, just input on variable totaltime
    */
var totaltime = 10;

function update(percent) {
  var deg;
  if (percent < (totaltime / 2)) {
    deg = 90 + (360 * percent / totaltime);
    $('.pie').css('background-image',
      'linear-gradient(' + deg + 'deg, transparent 50%, white 50%),linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%, transparent 50%)'
    );
  } else if (percent >= (totaltime / 2)) {
    deg = -90 + (360 * percent / totaltime);
    $('.pie').css('background-image',
      'linear-gradient(' + deg + 'deg, transparent 50%, #1fbba6 50%),linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%, transparent 50%)'
    );
  }
}
var count = parseInt($('#time').text());
myCounter = setInterval(function() {
  count -= 1;
  $('#time').html(count);
  update(count);
  console.log(count);
  if (count === 0) {
    clearInterval(myCounter);
    alert("Reached 0 SEC");
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300);
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  background: #b4f2ea;
}

.pie {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #1fbba6;
  border: 2px solid #1fbba6;
  float: left;
  margin: 2em;
}

.pie .block {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

#time {
  font-size: 3em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  left: 43%;
  color: #999999;
}

.degree {
  /*90 + ( 360 * .1 )*/
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, white 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pie degree">
  <span class="block"></span>
  <span id="time">10</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I want also to show an alert("Reached 0 SEC"); after reaching 0 sec

Comment: I updated the example :) and added the `alert()` to the condition: 
`if (count === 0) {
    clearInterval(myCounter);
    alert("Reached 0 SEC");
  }`

Comment: typically looking at the screen alert is showing at 1sec. Technically i need if the count is 0 then its triggering alert. But is there a way to show alert on screen after 0 sec are done.

Comment: It decrements to 0, and when it reaches it, it shows the alert, I updated the example and added console.log so you can verify, if you set the condition to < 0, you will see -1 in you counter

Comment: Where I need to set this `condition<0`